# Getting HTTP bad request when using google integration

Tags: java, android

I am getting the error HTTP bad request at the time of using google plus api .

```
public class OAuthActivity extends Activity {

    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEdit;
    private Person profile;

    final static int HTTP_RESPONSE_503 = 503;

    String status="status";
    String status_value="";
    String user_id_key="userid";
    String user_id="";
    String name_key="name" ;
    String name="" ;
    String user_type="user_type";
    String planidkey="plan_id";

    String login_status="";
    String username="",passwd="";
    String not_valid="Wrong Credentials";
    String valid="success";
    String plan_id_value="";
    boolean status_flag=false;

    SQLiteDatabase readfromdb,writeindb;
    DatabaseHelper postplanner_dbhelper;
    ContentValues values;
    int ordervalues;

    ProgressDialog pdia;

    SharedPreferencesCredentialStore credentialStore;
    Dialog type_dilog;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        //       new OAuthRequestTokenTask(this).execute();
    }


    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        WebView webview = new WebView(this);
        webview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        setContentView(webview);



        postplanner_dbhelper=new DatabaseHelper(this);

        String googleAuthorizationRequestUrl = new GoogleAuthorizationRequestUrl(
                SharedPreferencesCredentialStore.CLIENT_ID,
                SharedPreferencesCredentialStore.REDIRECT_URI,
                SharedPreferencesCredentialStore.SCOPE).build();

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {      
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                if (url.startsWith(SharedPreferencesCredentialStore.REDIRECT_URI)) {
                    try {
                        if (url.indexOf("code=") != -1) {
                            // Url is like http://localhost/?code=4/Z5DgC1IxNL-muPsrE2Sjy9zQn2pF




                            String code = url.substring(
                                    SharedPreferencesCredentialStore.REDIRECT_URI.length() + 7,
                                    url.length());

                            AccessTokenResponse accessTokenResponse = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeGrant(
                                    new NetHttpTransport(),
                                    new JacksonFactory(),
                                    SharedPreferencesCredentialStore.CLIENT_ID,
                                    SharedPreferencesCredentialStore.CLIENT_SECRET,
                                    code, SharedPreferencesCredentialStore.REDIRECT_URI).execute();

                            credentialStore = SharedPreferencesCredentialStore
                            .getInstance(prefs);
                            credentialStore.write(accessTokenResponse);
                            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                            //*********fatch access token google plus ***************       
                            String _email = fetchGoogleEmail(accessTokenResponse.accessToken);
                            retrieveProfile();

                            Log.e("idddd",""+profile);
                            Log.e("idddd",""+profile.getId());

                            prefEdit=prefs.edit();
                            prefEdit.putString("gpuserid", profile.getId());
                            if(_email!="") {
                                Log.i("I","AN I AM NOT EMPTY");
                                prefEdit.putString("gpemail", _email);
                            } // # end if if mail not empty
                            prefEdit.commit();

                            new loginDetails().execute();

                            //finish();
                        }else if (url.indexOf("error=") != -1) {
                            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            SharedPreferencesCredentialStore.getInstance(prefs)
                            .clearCredentials();
                            showAlertMessage();
                        }
                        /*else {
                            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            SharedPreferencesCredentialStore.getInstance(prefs)
                                    .clearCredentials();
                            startActivity(new Intent(
                                    OAuthActivity.this,
                                    Login_Webservice.class));
                            finish();
                        }*/

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }


        });

        webview.loadUrl(googleAuthorizationRequestUrl);
    }

    private void retrieveProfile() {
        try {



            JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
            HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();

            SharedPreferencesCredentialStore credentialStore = SharedPreferencesCredentialStore
            .getInstance(prefs);

            AccessTokenResponse accessTokenResponse = credentialStore.read();

            GoogleAccessProtectedResource accessProtectedResource = new GoogleAccessProtectedResource(
                    accessTokenResponse.accessToken, transport, jsonFactory,
                    SharedPreferencesCredentialStore.CLIENT_ID,
                    SharedPreferencesCredentialStore.CLIENT_SECRET,
                    accessTokenResponse.refreshToken);

            Builder b = Plus.builder(transport, jsonFactory).setApplicationName("Kimunita/1.0");

            b.setHttpRequestInitializer(accessProtectedResource);
            Plus plus = b.build();
            profile = plus.people().get("me").execute();

            //updateViews();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    //***************Google +code Gourav++++++++++++++++++*/
    private String fetchGoogleEmail(String token) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (token == "") {
            return "";
        }
        JSONObject json = null;
        String email = "";
        String gpUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token="
            + token;


        Log.e("urll ouathactivity", "" + gpUrl);

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(gpUrl);
        HttpResponse response;

        try {

            response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            Log.e("try", "" + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                Log.e("entity=====", "" + entity);
                if (entity != null) {
                    InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                    String jsonstr = convertStreamToString(instream);
                    Log.e("jsonstr======", "" + jsonstr);
                    instream.close();
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonstr);
                        email = jsonObj.getString("email");
                        Log.e("email G+ ouathactivity", "" + email);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } else {
                    json = 
                        genError(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(),
                                response.getStatusLine().toString());
                }
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            try {
                json = genError(HTTP_RESPONSE_503,
                        "Exception: ClientProtocolException");
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                json = genError(HTTP_RESPONSE_503, "Exception:IOException");
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {

            try {
                json = genError(HTTP_RESPONSE_503, "Exception:JSONException");
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                json = genError(HTTP_RESPONSE_503,
                        "Exception: Exception " + e.toString());
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        } finally {
            httpGet.abort();
        }
        Log.i("GOOGLE +"," EMAIL ===="+email);
        return email;
    }

    private String fetchDataCorrespondingID(String gpuserid) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        JSONObject json = null;
        JSONObject json1 = null;

        //String gpUrl=AppUtil.server_URL+"/web-service.php?action=GPlogin&id="+gpuserid;
        String gp_email=prefs.getString("gpemail", "");
        String gpUrl=AppUtil.server_URL+"/web-service.php?action=GPlogin&id="+gp_email;
        Log.e("urll ouathactivity",""+gpUrl);

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(gpUrl);
        HttpResponse response;

        try {
            response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) 
            {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                if (entity != null) {
                    InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                    String jsonstr =convertStreamToString(instream);
                    instream.close();
                    try
                    {
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonstr);

                        JSONObject data=jsonObj.getJSONObject("response");
                        status_value=data.getString(status);
//                      String responseMsg = jsonObj.getString("response");
                        Log.i("data", data.toString());

                        if(status_value.equalsIgnoreCase(not_valid))
                        {
                            status_flag=false;

                        }else if(status_value.equalsIgnoreCase(valid))
                        {

                            status_value=data.getString(status);
                            Log.i("status_value", status_value.toString());
                            user_id=data.getString(user_id_key);
                            Log.i("user_id", user_id.toString());
                            name=data.getString(name_key);
                            Log.i("name", name.toString());
                            plan_id_value=data.getString(planidkey);
                            Log.i("plan_id_value", plan_id_value.toString());
                            status_flag=true;

                        }else
                        {
                            status_flag=false;
                            pdia.dismiss();
                        }

                    } 
                    catch (JSONException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                } 
                else {
                    json = genError(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(), response.getStatusLine().toString());
                }
            } 
        }
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            try {
                json = genError(HTTP_RESPONSE_503, "Exception: ClientProtocolException");
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                json = genError(HTTP_RESPONSE_503, "Exception: IOException");
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {

            try {
                json = genError(HTTP_RESPONSE_503, "Exception: JSONException");
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }  
        } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                json = genError(HTTP_RESPONSE_503, "Exception: Exception " + e.toString());
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        } finally {
            httpGet.abort();
        }
        return status_value;



    }

    public static JSONObject genError(Integer code, String message) throws JSONException {
        // TODO: HTTP-Status (404, etc), for now return status line
        String msg = "{error: {code: \"" + code.toString() + "\", message: \"" + message + "\"}}";
        Log.e("EEEEEEEEEE",msg );
        return new JSONObject("{error: {code: \"" + code.toString() + "\", message: \"" + message + "\"}}");

    }

    public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return sb.toString();

    }

}
```

> 02-11 12:37:34.869: W/System.err(13631):
>   com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 400 Bad Request
>   02-11 12:37:34.869: W/System.err(13631):  at
>   com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:669)
>   02-11 12:37:34.879: W/System.err(13631):  at
>   com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.draft10.AccessTokenRequest.executeUnparsed(AccessTokenRequest.java:459)
>   02-11 12:37:34.879: W/System.err(13631):  at
>   com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.draft10.AccessTokenRequest.execute(AccessTokenRequest.java:475)
>   02-11 12:37:34.879: W/System.err(13631):  at
>   com.Planner.postplanner.OAuthActivity$1.onPageFinished(OAuthActivity.java:181)
>   02-11 12:37:34.879: W/System.err(13631):  at
>   android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:318)
>   02-11 12:37:34.879: W/System.err(13631):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 02-11
>   12:37:34.879: W/System.err(13631):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 02-11 12:37:34.879:
>   W/System.err(13631):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517) 02-11
>   12:37:34.879: W/System.err(13631):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 02-11
>   12:37:34.879: W/System.err(13631):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 02-11 12:37:34.879:
>   W/System.err(13631):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
>   02-11 12:37:34.879: W/System.err(13631):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760) 02-11
>   12:37:34.879: W/System.err(13631):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: what are we supposed to do with this huge blob of code? Have you done some investigation for your problem?

Comment: i am getting the com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 400 Bad Request  ,i want to resolve this ,i had searched it ,they are saying it is due to the Version ,i dont know ,where to add the version for solving this problem